# JBoss Fuse ESB - moving files between servers

Tags: apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse

We are trying to create an interface to move files from a linux server to the server that JBoss Fuse is installed on (also linux). Is there a way to use the Camel File endpoint to do this? We do not want to use FTP of SFTP to do this.

Comment: You can probably use the Camel File and use a NFS share between the machines. See [here](http://superuser.com/q/300662/196634) how to do the share.

Comment: If the network disks are shared then it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use FTP, you have to share the linux server directory and mount it on the jboss fuse server, than you can use the camel file component.